# Is there a way to select and proportion rows based on their value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, categories, rows

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
   a          b  c   d
1  2005-01-01 0 ... ...
2  2005-02-22 1 ... ...
3  2005-04-02 0 ... ...
4  2005-12-01 3 ... ...
5  2006-03-03 0 ... ...
6  2006-06-08 1 ... ...
7  2006-10-11 0 ... ...
8  2006-12-02 4 ... ...
9  2007-03-24 0 ... ...
10 2007-04-06 2 ... ...
11 2008-01-28 0 ... ...
12 2008-08-19 0 ... ...
13 2008-09-12 0 ... ...
14 2008-12-12 2 ... ...
15 2009-05-27 0 ... ...
16    ...     . ... ...
```

And I want to select all the rows in the year 2005 and view how many of them are 0,1,2,3 or 4 for example (so combined with column b). Maybe with proportions? For example that the result would be:

```
output:
2005
0    1    2    3    4
20%  20%  20%  20%  20%
```

I tried `table(year(DF$a), c=DF$b)` however this only yields an overview of all the years, and no proportions or anything like that. I tried piping this into a proportions function with `%>%`, however this doesn't work.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `table` and `proportions` to get the share per Year, where you can give a `margin` in `proportions`, here `1`, to do it per row.

```
proportions(table(format(DF$a, "%Y"), DF$b), 1) * 100
#         0   1   2   3   4
#  2005  50  25   0  25   0
#  2006  50  25   0   0  25
#  2007  50   0  50   0   0
#  2008  75   0  25   0   0
#  2009 100   0   0   0   0
```

Data:

```
DF <- structure(list(a = structure(c(12784, 12836, 12875, 13118, 13210, 
13307, 13432, 13484, 13596, 13609, 13906, 14110, 14134, 14225, 
14391), class = "Date"), b = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), c = c("...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "..."), d = c("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you once again @GKi ! So how did you get it to look at it per year? When I tried proportions earlier it calculated it for the entire data frame.

Comment: You can give `margin = 1` to make it per row.

Comment: To get just the row for 2005, assign the results of proportion to a variable, like `result` and subset with `result["2005",]`

Answer (score 0):

You can `count` occurrence of each `b` value in the year, calculate ratio and get the data in wide format (if needed) using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  count(year = lubridate::year(a), b) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  arrange(b) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = b, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

#   year   `0`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2005    50    25     0    25     0
#2  2006    50    25     0     0    25
#3  2007    50     0    50     0     0
#4  2008    75     0    25     0     0
#5  2009   100     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: And to get only the rows for 2005, add `%>% filter(year == 2005)` after the `pivot_wider()` step